# "page x of y" in a table, how to allign the text within a table instead of the page border?

Tags: itext7

I was able to create page x of y using the Building Blocks example of [Chapter 7: Handling events; setting viewer preferences and writer properties](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties) **Solving the "Page X of Y" problem**. In the example, the texts of "page x of y" are alligned via a `Canvas` with the page border. But very often is that the "x of y" shall be put into a table like this:
[image]

In such cases, the text shall be alligned within the table, how to do this?
In my application, the table which includes the page x of y shall be shown on each page and still at a fixed position, i.e. at the right upper position of a page. And the table format and size will not change for the whole document.

Comment: Is this a footer table that is the same across all the pages (except variable page number part), or is it a regular table with insertions of page numbers? Please provide a bit more complete outline of what you are trying to achieve because the implementation depends on the final goal.

Comment: To expand on Alexey's remarks: The X of Y examples writes textual content to absolute positions in the page using lower-level api calls. If your table changes in size or position on different pages, this might not be good approach. This is why we need to know a bit more about the outline and goal of your project.

Comment: I updated my problem description. The table will not change size or position for all pages. It will be very kind of you, if you can also tell me if the table will change positions, what will be the solution? Replace texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to fit the whole table, you would want to increase the bottom margin of the `Document`:

```
Document document = new Document(pdf);
document.setBottomMargin(100);
```

After that, you can still use `Canvas` to add a table instead of a paragraph. I will base the answer on the `PageXofY` example you refer to.

First of all, create a usual `Table`:

```
Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] {50, 50}));
table.addCell(new Cell(4, 1));
table.addCell(new Cell().add("Filename: "));
table.addCell(new Cell().add("Issue date: "));
Paragraph pageXofY = new Paragraph().
        add("Page " + String.valueOf(pageNumber) + " of ").
        add(new Image(placeholder));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(pageXofY));
table.addCell(new Cell().add("Location: "));
```

Note that we still use a placeholder `FormXObject` to store the total number of pages.

Change the `side` to font size, it is `12` in our case. Create placeholder like this:

```
placeholder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, 2 * side, side));
```

Make a slight change to the `writeTotal()` method. The `y` position of the text has been changed to `-descent`:

```
public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
    canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
        0, -descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
}
```

Now all you need to to is add this table to the proper place on the page:

```
float marginX = 36;
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, new Rectangle(marginX, 10, pageSize.getWidth() - marginX * 2, 100));
canvas.add(table);
pdfCanvas.release();
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Magic, it works, many thanks. The only very very tiny problem in my application is to allign text "Y" with "Page X of ", I have to tune variable `descent` a little bit in the `writeTotal()`. A **new** problem is the TOC (table of content), when the TOC pages are removed from the end of the document to the begin of the document, seem this causes problem to generate Page X of Y. Shall I start a new post or just continue to ask here?

Comment: I think it's better to start the new post as the problem with TOC is not related to the footer table problem.